# Problemas na instalação do Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Efetuei a instalação do Visual Studio 2015 Community e toda vez que entro ele solicita uma reparação. Tentei desinstalar mas não permite.

Alguém pode ajudar a desinstalar o Studio 2015 Community?

Comment: Você tem a ISO de instalação?

Comment: Faça o download do ISO [aqui](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/products/visual-studio-community-vs.aspx) e tente reparar/desinstalar.

Answer (score 0):

Você tem uma forma de **forçar** a desinstalação do Visual Studio 2015, vou-lhe mostrar como procedi à uns tempos atrás quando tive exatamente o mesmo problema:

```
C:\vs_ultimate.exe /uninstall /force
```

Corre esse comando no seu **CMD** . Atenção que no meu caso era esse o diretório, estava localizado no disco **C:** e eu estava usando a versão **Ultimate** .

Você terá que colocar a diretoria a que corresponde o seu.

Comment: Isso só vai funcionar se C:/ por acaso for a unidade da ISO do visual studio. Caso contrario, não vai encontrar o executavel informado.

Comment: O que eu é que eu disse na resposta ? Eu mostrei consoante o meu diretório, você tem que ver qual é a unidade do ISO, aquele diretório é, no meu caso, o diretório da minha unidade

Answer (score -2):

Isso em principio deve-se ao facto que você tem o seu Windows corrompido. Use o comando sfc /scannow no cmd para report os ficheiros de sistema e por fin faça um chkdsk ao seu c:

```
sfc /scannow
```

Comment: Pense bem na sua resposta e veja se não tem nada a ver com o que eu disse.

Comment: Vá lá, se o instalador estivesse corrompido nem conseguia instalar. Pois o instalar é um executável e você não consegue correr executável corrompidos

Comment: Pode manter o seu voto, a mim pouco ou nada me chateia. Só para dizer que o Visual Studio copia ficheiros para a pasta do Windows como qualquer outro programa e este pode ter alterado uma dll ou outro programa que agora tem assinaturas diferentes, se for um  ficheiro de sistema esse comando vai ajudar. Relembro que estamos a falar de problemas de instalação muitas vezes o problema até difícil de detectar pelo menos tem ai algo para iniciar.